# Bluetooth BLE comms w/ CodenameOne

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, codenameone

(originally asked on GoogleGroup support)
If you are experiencing an issue please mention the full platform your issue applies to:
IDE: NetBeans
Desktop OS: Mac
Simulator: none, due to Bluetooth usage which is not available on Simulator
Device: Android phone
Bluetooth device: pedometer

It seems BLE support is unreliable. I turn on my Bluetooth device that I'm trying to connect to (a pedometer), then on the phone I start scanning for the device, and sometimes it picks up, sometimes not. If it does pick up, I try to connect using the address, and I get a "Could not connect to device". (incidentally, if I use isConnected(), it throws an exception saying it was never connected.  I assumed it would just return false)
I'm trying to duplicate a native iOS app, which has no issue connecting to the pedometer every time.

I've been searching for a "best practices" on BLE comms, but can not find anything substantial.  The link the Cordova docs are cumbersome due to requiring translation into the Codename One lib.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to init, scan, connect? I have an app that is working for the most part on both platforms.

Comment: Also, are you trying to use reconnect? Do you disconnect and close, or just disconnect? I have trouble connecting again after disconnecting. The only thing working so far is exiting the app after disconnecting, but then the user needs to launch the app again to reconnect. I haven't solved this so far. I'd suggest seeing if you normally have success connecting after a fresh launch and no success after disconnecting and reconnecting without fully exiting the app.

Comment: @JamesH this is on [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com) so it uses [this library](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone) whose native code for Android is [here](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone/tree/master/CN1Bluethooth/native/android/com/codename1/bluetoothle) and for iOS is [here](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone/tree/master/CN1Bluethooth/native/ios)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the [https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/codenameone-discussions/b2b022e0-47e3-4a4c-9c33-4998ce2ef65e%40googlegroups.com[thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/codenameone-discussions/b2b022e0-47e3-4a4c-9c33-4998ce2ef65e%40googlegroups.com%5Bthread) in the discussion forum] the API is callback based and expects you to wait for a response from the device asynchronously.

This is because we [ported a Cordova plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) to implement this functionality in a stable way. Since JavaScript doesn't support synchronous calls those weren't added.

We thought about extending the implementation but we also wanted to keep it as close as possible to the original so changes there can be brought in quickly.